# Functional Error in Excel Array Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table on which I want to perform to array operation. Here is my table
[snapshot of Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtzy9.png).

Table Data

```
+-------+---------+------+-------+
| Stock |  Date   | Open | Close |
+-------+---------+------+-------+
| GOOG  | 10-1-12 |  759 |   762 |
| GOOG  | 10-2-12 |  765 |   757 |
| GOOG  | 10-3-12 |  756 |   763 |
| GOOG  | 10-4-12 |  762 |   768 |
+-------+---------+------+-------+
```

My question now is why I am getting different values for the exact same formula in column E. I performed the similar process in column G  but this time selecting `G2:G5` and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Formula in all cells in column E: `=D2:D5-C2:C5`

Comment: What is the formula supposed to do? What do you think subtracting an array of values from another array of values will result in? Your formula `=D2:D5-C2:C5` results in difference of first value found in `D2:D5` and  first value found in `C2:C5`. First value found depends on the row the formula is put in. In row 2 it is `D2-C2`, in row 3 it is `D3-C3` and so on.

Comment: Are you looking for this : `=SUM($D$2:$D$5)-SUM($C$2:$C$5)`?. Also as @AxelRichter explained, to understand whats select the cell and go to Formulas Menu and select Evaluate formula. There you can see step by step whats going on.

Comment: @alex I was trying to do `{=SUM(D2:D5-C2:C5)}` And out of curiosity I entered the `=D2:D5-C2:C5` in all cells only to find out that it returns different value for each cell. And the above formula shouldn't it always return the value `D2-C2` as only one cell is selected in the resultant array which gets filled by the top row calculation. And irrespective of location the result should always be the same as I am entering same exact formula in each cell, not simultaneously.

Comment: To detect how `{=SUM(D2:D5-C2:C5)}` works, do exactly what @cyboashu suggested. Use the formula evaluator. Trying on `=D2:D5-C2:C5` outside array formula context will not be successfully. And `{=D2:D5-C2:C5}` is in matrix context but results in a matrix as result which a single cell cannot display. So your column `G` shows this matrix result and this is what `SUM` is summing then. And this sum then **can** be displayed in one cell.